# Why has this question had so many more views than average?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5784/how-thick-is-it-reasonable-for-the-walls-of-a-steel-gas-pipeline-to-be) has had over 1600 views in 2 days. Which is orders of magnitude more than the average views for questions on the Engineering StackExchange site. From a quick scroll through recent questions it looks like the average views per question is less than 100.

Any ideas on why this may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to the 'Hot Network Questions' effect.  StackExchange uses an algorithm to search all the sites for questions which are 'hot'.  I don't know the details of how they decide, but I've noticed that questions which receive multiple answers very shortly after posting often make it to the list.

Once a question is considered 'hot', it shows up in the list which is on the lower right-hand side of every SE site.  This shows the question to an audience which is many orders of magnitude larger than the one that frequents this site.  If the question is truly interesting to a broad audience, then the effect gets amplified, and the question can stay on the list for many days.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! I never really paid much attention to the hot network questions. I looked into it a little more and it seems that the algorithm to decide hot questions is discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page